# Need a code sample showing how to post to Wordpress using Codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, xml-rpc

Does anyone have a code sample they can share that show how to make a basic blog post to Wordpress using the CodeIgniter xml-rpc library?

So far, I have this, which always results in "Bad login/pass combination", although I am using the correct combination.

```
function doPost(){

    $this->load->library('xmlrpc');

    $bloguser = "theUserid";
    $blogpass = "thePassword";
    $blogid = 0; //I've tried 0 and 1 here. 
    $post['title'] = "The title of a new post";
    $post['description'] = "The body of the post.";
    $this->xmlrpc->server("http://localhost/blog/xmlrpc.php", 80);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('metaWeblog.newPost');

    $this->xmlrpc->request = array($blogid, $bloguser, $blogpass, $post, TRUE);
    if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
    {
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After much gnashing of teeth, this seems to work:

```
function doPost(){

    $this->load->library('xmlrpc');

    $bloguser = "theUserID";
    $blogpass = "thePassword";
    $blogid = 1; 
    $publishImmediately = TRUE;

    $thePost = array(array('title'  => array('this is the title','string'),
                            'description'    => array('this is the description','string')
                            ),
                     'struct');               


    $myPost = "my post";
    //$this->xmlrpc->set_debug(TRUE);
    $this->xmlrpc->server("http://url.to/xmlrpc.php", 80);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('metaWeblog.newPost');

    $request = array($blogid, $bloguser, $blogpass, $thePost, $publishImmediately);

    $this->xmlrpc->request($request);
    $result = $this->xmlrpc->send_request();

    if ( !$result )
    {
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

The important part is to note the struct for the elements of the actual post.

Comment: Would appreciate any feedback to know if there are different / better ways to do this.

Comment: any news? Have you found better way?