# how to send xml-rpc to a codeigniter site?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, xml-rpc

I have a codeigniter XML-RPC server and client setup. Everything works fine. My problem is following:

Another application will be sending XML-RPC to my codeigniter XML-RPC server, and I need to give them instructions. I know how to send from CI -> CI .. how how does another application that is NON-CI send XML to CI?

I was trying to get CI to give me a XML dump of the structure, but I was not able to figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated. Basically, I need to know how a NON-CI application can send XML-RPC to my CI XML-RPC server.

Comment: May be web service you are looking for. Nusoap or REST is good one for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a code sample showing how to post to Wordpress using Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324360/need-a-code-sample-showing-how-to-post-to-wordpress-using-codeigniter)